# Resource distribution algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I'm looking for efficient algorithm distributing atomic resources with arbitrar weight among a number of buckets with random capacity. Buckets can be added or removed, and resources from removed buckets should be redistributed among remaining ones. Are there any known algorithms solving this problem? Consider both situations when you can move already distributed resources and not.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  Is any arbitrary division OK?  Are you trying to minimize/maximize some objective function?  Do you care about the running time of the algorithm?  Have you looked at algorithms for bin packing?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

Comment: Thanks, looks like bin packing is exactly what i'm looking for!